# Defining a derivative on a custom function

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to define a derivative that acts on a custom function, $f$, such that when it acts, it increments one of the arguments of by 1. f is not defined; I just want to use it to keep track of derivatives. I know I could define a separate operator to do this, but this function, $f$, will be multiplied by other functions that need differentiating, so I thought it easier to define how derivatives act on f. My attempt thus far:

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f[a,b,c,d]][x1, x2, x3, x4] = f[a,b,c,d]
```

However, when I go to evaluate this derivative, I get

```
Input: D[f[a,b,c,d][x1, x2, x3, x4], x1]
Output: f[a,b,c,d]^{1,0,0,0}[x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

whereas, I would hope to get something like:

```
Input: D[f[a,b,c,d][x1, x2, x3, x4], x1]
Output: f[a+1,b,c,d][x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

The derivative definition only works specifically for the exact syntax in the definition, and not with any other arguments apart from a,b,c,d:

```
Input: D[f[a,b,c,d][x1, x2, x3, x4], x1]
Output: f[a+1,b,c,d]
```

Any suggestions on how to obtain the second listed output?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Clear all your previous definitions, try `Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f] = CKB[#1 + 1, #2, #3, #4] &`, and report back.

Comment: You're using `Slot` the wrong way. Also, I don't see why you expect the output to be in terms of `f` if you define the right-hand side to be `CKB` in the first line.

Comment: @Jens My mistake - CKB should be f. Edited.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.
Using Slot isn't necessary - since I don't fully understand how it works, I'm editing the question to functions without Slot.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I tried:
`Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f] = f[a + 1, b, c, d]` and
`Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][x1, x2, x3, x4] = f[a + 1, b, c, d]`, but I'm still unable to generate the output desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that all you need is `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`):

```
Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][a_, b_, c_, d_] := f[a + 1, b, c, d]
```

Now let us evaluate some derivatives:

```
D[f[x, y, z, p], {x, 1}] (* with respect to that first argument *)
D[f[x, y, z, p], {y, 1}] (* with respect to any other argument *)

(*Out: 
f[1 + x, y, z, p]
Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z, p]
*)
```